# c# upload in real time from client to server to amazon s3

Tags: c#, wcf, amazon-s3

Good morning, I have an desktop app that uploads files to a WCF service and then WCF Service uploads to Amazon S3.

This is my WCF method that receives the file and uploads to S3.

```
public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
        {
            config = new AmazonS3Config();
            config.CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP;
            accessKeyID = "XXXXXXX"; 
            secretAccessKeyID = "YYYYYYYY";
            client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID, config);

            int chunkSize = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream writeStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                do
                {
                    // read bytes from input stream
                    int bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;

                    // simulates slow connection
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);

                    // write bytes to output stream
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                } while (true);

                // report end
                Console.WriteLine("Done!");

                // start the uploading to S3
                PutObjectRequest fileRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
                fileRequest.WithInputStream(writeStream);
                fileRequest.Key = "testfile.pdf";
                fileRequest.WithBucketName("tempbucket");
                fileRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private;
                fileRequest.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard;
                client.PutObject(fileRequest);

                writeStream.Close();
            }

        }
```

On my client I get the progress in real time when upload the file to the WCF Service but when I get the **100% complete it doesnt mean that the file has already uploaded to S3**, so I would like to know if its possible to being uploading the file to S3 while Im writing the stream (inside of the using

```
(System.IO.MemoryStream writeStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
```

Is this possible? Any guideline on how to do it?

Appreciate in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is slightly unclear (at least to me). How does your client show progress in real time?

Comment: WCF has a feature for that. <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" openTimeout="00:2:00"
                 closeTimeout="00:2:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:2:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:2:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864">
        </binding>

Answer (score 0):

You can use **InputStream** property of **[PutObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_PutObjectRequest.htm)**

```
public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
{
    config = new AmazonS3Config();
    config.CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP;
    accessKeyID = "XXXXXXX"; 
    secretAccessKeyID = "YYYYYYYY";
    client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID,secretAccessKeyID,config);

    int chunkSize = 2048;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

    PutObjectRequest fileRequest = new PutObjectRequest();

    fileRequest.Key = "testfile.pdf";
    fileRequest.WithBucketName("tempbucket");
    fileRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private;
    fileRequest.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard;

    using (fileRequest.InputStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
      do
      {
         // read bytes from input stream
         int bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
         if (bytesRead == 0) break;

         // simulates slow connection
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);

         // write bytes to output stream
         fileRequest.InputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       } while (true);

       // report end
       Console.WriteLine("Done!");

       client.PutObject(fileRequest);

    }
 }
```

Comment: This works but still have the same problem. The client knows that the file was already begin uploaded to server but when you call client.PutObject(fileRequest) because is outside of the do while then have to wait until server uploads that stream to S3.

Comment: Do it Async.. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/sdk-net-async-api.html

Comment: I think will get the same result. I have to start uploading inside the do while... I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604916/s3-multi-part-upload-exception  using Multiplart upload

Comment: here the documentation about multi upload : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend uploading the file to the WCF as chunks instead of a stream. I did so and it works just fine. also you need to return a message of the actual bytes written to the amazon later on you can increase the progress bar based on that. I know it will cause you to write a while loop in the client application but it will help you to show the progress with 100% accuracy for large files. Your WCF function should take the parameter like these

```
[DataContract]
class RemoteFileInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    Byte[] myChunk;
    [DataMember]
    long myOffset;
    // other stuff you think you need to be sent each time.

}
```

Comment: How can I send chunks instead of a stream? But does Amazon S3 support to upload chunk bytes?

Comment: It is not related to the Amazon S3, using WCF class RemoteFileInfo remove the stream data member and add another data member which should be an array of bytes. also you need another data member for the offset.